# how to remove all options from a dijit/form/select?

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, dijit.form

I use a very simple dijit/form/select on my webppage
I add few options by code like this :

```
option1 = { value: "o1", label: "option 1", selected: false };
option2 = { value: "o2", label: "option 2", selected: true };

this.mySelect.addOption([option1, option2]);
```

It's working. 
However when I try to clear my dijit/form/select using this code :

```
this.mySelect.removeOption(this.mySelect.getOption());
```

All my options are gone except the selected one.

I try using a .reset or even a .value = '' but nothing worked.

So how to remove all options from a dijit/form/select ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the answer is pretty simple, but not well docummented `(it's pretty hard to find, like all dojo related stuff)`

```
this.mySelect.removeOption(lang.clone(option1));
this.mySelect.removeOption(lang.clone(option2));

this.mySelect.store = null;
this.mySelect.set('value', '');
this.mySelect._setDisplay(""); //This line alone should do the trick
```

> As in the comments, the last line should do the trick, but this way you can be sure that the `select` element gets cleared.

**Demo:** <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78mz0r5s/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Glad to help @skerdreux